# (C#) Why am I getting the message "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, but decided to try and program something challenging. I decided to program a game of One Row Nim in which you play against a computer, where the computer always wins. I finished my code, and am getting the error "not all code paths return a value." I think I know what this means, but I'm not sure why I'm getting it.

```
using System;
    namespace OneRowNimThing {
    class NimSetup {
        static string OneRowNim(int count, int turn, int prevPlayerInput) {
        int playerInput, CPUInput, newCount;

        if (turn == 0) {
            if (count <= 0) {
                return "You Lose!";
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("It is now your turn.");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to take 1, 2, or 3 pieces?");
                playerInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (playerInput >= 4) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid input.", playerInput);
                    OneRowNim(count, turn, prevPlayerInput);
                }
                else if (playerInput < 1) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid input.", playerInput);
                    OneRowNim(count, turn, prevPlayerInput);
                }
                else {
                    newCount = count - playerInput;
                    Console.WriteLine("You have taken {0} pieces, there are {1} pieces remaining.", playerInput, newCount);
                    OneRowNim(newCount, 1, playerInput);
                }
            }
        }

        if (turn == 1) {
            if (count <= 0) {
                return "You Win!";
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("It is now the computer's turn.");
                CPUInput = 4 - prevPlayerInput;
                newCount = count - CPUInput;
                Console.WriteLine("The computer took {0} pieces. There are {1} pieces remaining.", CPUInput, newCount);
                OneRowNim(newCount, 0, prevPlayerInput);
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        OneRowNim(12, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't know how Nim Works, it's essentially a game in which you take pieces out of a pile, and whoever takes the last one wins.

Comment: where is "return" for else-clause ?

Comment: maybe you need to use `return OneRowNim(newCount, 1, playerInput);`

Comment: One quick fix would be to add a `return` before your recursive calls of `OneRowNim`, but you shouldn't be recursing in the first place, I think.

Comment: You have to have a return statement when `turn == 0 and count > 0`,  when `turn == 1 and count > 0` and when `turn is not equal to 0 and 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method signature states that it returns a string.

However, the if-else cases make the flow not always returning string.

1. turn == 0, count > 0, no return
2. turn == 1, count > 0, no return
3. turn > 1, no return

Make sure that your method returns something anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `return` statement in `else` constructs. You need to return `string` value from each else clauses.

The [return statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks that turn can be any 32 bit integer, so from its point of view, there are cases other than 0 or 1. And for those there are no return paths.

Answer (score 0):

"Not all code paths return a value" refers to the fact that there is a possible path through your `OneRowNim` method that does not hit a `return` statement. Tommy is correct in which code paths.

The fix is that you have to make sure you're returning your recursive calls. Essentially:

```
if (playerInput >= 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid input.", playerInput);
    return OneRowNim(count, turn, prevPlayerInput);
}
```

Also, I know this isn't what you asked for, but C# has a cool way of resolving variables inline a string:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{playerInput} is not a valid input.");
```

Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Add return ""; in else part of if (count <= 0) at both place.
Replace below code with your existing code.

```
    if (turn == 0) {
        if (count <= 0) {
            return "You Lose!";
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("It is now your turn.");
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to take 1, 2, or 3 pieces?");
            playerInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (playerInput >= 4) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid input.", playerInput);
                OneRowNim(count, turn, prevPlayerInput);
            }
            else if (playerInput < 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid input.", playerInput);
                OneRowNim(count, turn, prevPlayerInput);
            }
            else {
                newCount = count - playerInput;
                Console.WriteLine("You have taken {0} pieces, there are {1} pieces remaining.", playerInput, newCount);
                OneRowNim(newCount, 1, playerInput);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    if (turn == 1) {
        if (count <= 0) {
            return "You Win!";
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("It is now the computer's turn.");
            CPUInput = 4 - prevPlayerInput;
            newCount = count - CPUInput;
            Console.WriteLine("The computer took {0} pieces. There are {1} pieces remaining.", CPUInput, newCount);
            OneRowNim(newCount, 0, prevPlayerInput);
        }
        return "";
    }
```